# How is this possible that the same serializer produces different results in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am facing a rather annoying issue than a difficult one. The problem is the following:

- a given djangorestframework ModelSerializer class called UserSerializer serializes the authenticated user instance with proper image result from the model's FileField attribute
- when calling some generic API view of djangorestframework, and using the exact same serializer, the image path receives a domain address by default

Django version: 4.2.2,
Django REST Framework version: 3.14

**What I do want to receive in output: the path of the stored file as mentioned in Django documentation (MEDIA_URL is 'media/'), without the localhost domain appended to it.**

The below image shows that in the RootLayout, I receive the correct path starting with /media/etc. so I append domain address from environmental variable depending on mode, while in UsersLayout, each user gets my MANUAL appended domain and an automatic one from somewhere.

[image]

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
path('change-password/<int:pk>', UserChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='auth_change_password'),  # ---- Untestable
path('languages/', LanguagesL.as_view()),  # ----------------------------------------------------------- Tested
path('password_reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),  # -----
path('payment/barion/ipn/', PaymentBarionIPN.as_view()),  # -------------------------------------------- Untestable
path('payment/barion/start/<int:pk>', UserSubscriptionCreateStart.as_view()),  # ----------------------- Untestable
path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),  # ----------------------------
path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),  # ---------------------------
path('user-factor-relation-strategies/', UserFactorRelationStrategiesLC.as_view()),  # ----------------- Tested
path('user-factor-relation-strategies/history/', UserFactorRelationStrategiesHistory.as_view()),  # -----
path('user-factor-relations/', UserFactorRelationsLC.as_view()),  # ------------------------------------ Tested
path('user-factor-relations/history/<int:pk>', UserFactorRelationsHistory.as_view()),  # ---------------
path('user-factors/', UserFactorsLC.as_view()),  # ----------------------------------------------------- Tested
path('user-factors/history/', UserFactorsHistory.as_view()),  # -----------------------------------------
path('user-operative-actions/', UserOperativeActionsLC.as_view()),  # ---------------------------------- Tested
path('user-operative-actions/history/', UserOperativeActionsHistory.as_view()),  # ----------------------
path('user-swots/', UserSwotsLC.as_view()),  # --------------------------------------------------------- Tested
path('user-swots/<int:pk>', UserSwotsRUD.as_view()),  # ------------------------------------------------ Tested
path('users/', UsersLC.as_view()),  # ------------------------------------------------------------------ Tested
path('users/<int:pk>', UsersRU.as_view()),  # ---------------------------------------------------------  Tested
path('users/authenticated/', AuthenticatedUser.as_view()),  # ------------------------------------------ Tested
]
```

These are the mentioned views

```
class UsersLC(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsStaffOrWriteOnly]
serializer_class = UserSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = User.objects.all().prefetch_related('usersubscription_set')
    email = self.request.query_params.get('email')
    return queryset.filter(email__icontains=email) if email else queryset

class AuthenticatedUser(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = UserSerializer

def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user

def get(self, request):
    return Response(self.serializer_class(self.get_object()).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is my serializer class

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
full_name = ReadOnlyField()
has_billing_information = ReadOnlyField()
has_valid_subscription = ReadOnlyField()
language_code = ReadOnlyField()
on_trial = ReadOnlyField()
usersubscription_set = UserSubscriptionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
valid_subscriptions = UserSubscriptionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    exclude = ('last_login',)
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
    model = User
    read_only_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff')

def create(self, validated_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

And finally, this is my model class

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)

class Meta:
    constraints = [models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(country__length__gte=2), name='User.country__min_length')]
    db_table = 'Users'

accepted_eula_and_privacy_policy = models.BooleanField(db_column='AcceptedEULAandPrivacyPolicy', default=False)
address_1 = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='Address 1', max_length=50)
address_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='Address 2', max_length=50)
city = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='City', max_length=50)
country = models.CharField(db_column='Country (ISO 3166-1)', default='HU', max_length=2)
email = models.EmailField(db_column='Email', max_length=50, unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='FirstName', max_length=255)
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, db_column='Image', max_length=1000, upload_to='API_Authentication/user/image/')
is_active = models.BooleanField(db_column='Active', default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(db_column='Staff', default=False)
job_title = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='JobTitle', max_length=50)
language = models.ForeignKey(Language, db_column='LanguageID', default=2, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='LastName', max_length=255)
phone_number = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='PhoneNumber', max_length=50)
registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_column='RegistrationDate')
tax_number = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='TaxNumber', max_length=13)
zip_code = models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='ZipCode', max_length=16)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

@property
def full_name(self):
    return f'{self.last_name} {self.first_name}' if self.first_name and self.last_name else None

@property
def has_billing_information(self):
    return (
        len(self.address_1) > 0
        and len(self.city) > 0
        and len(self.country) > 0
        and len(self.first_name) > 0
        and len(self.last_name) > 0
        and len(self.zip_code) > 0
    )

@property
def has_valid_subscription(self):
    has_valid_subscription = False
    for subscription in self.usersubscription_set.all():
        if subscription.validity_start < timezone.now() and subscription.validity_end > timezone.now():
            has_valid_subscription = True
            break
    return has_valid_subscription

@property
def language_code(self):
    return self.language.iso_639_1

@property
def on_trial(self):
    return not self.has_valid_subscription and self.registration_date + timedelta(days=3) > timezone.now()

@property
def valid_subscriptions(self):
    return self.usersubscription_set.filter(validity_end__gte=timezone.now(), validity_start__lte=timezone.now())

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

I would be delighted if you could offer me some tips, thank you!

Comment: I don't see a serializer for `image`? (EDIT: oh, right, you're `exclude`ing instead of `fields`ing, never mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DRF's `ImageField`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8b7e6f2e3405d6e71488db53f2dda515d5a336c6/rest_framework/fields.py#L1564) derives from [`FileField`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8b7e6f2e3405d6e71488db53f2dda515d5a336c6/rest_framework/fields.py#L1513) whose [`to_representation`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8b7e6f2e3405d6e71488db53f2dda515d5a336c6/rest_framework/fields.py#L1546) looks at your [serializer context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) which generally includes the Django `request` when DRF calls your serializers – but if you just invoke a serializer by hand, the context will be empty by default.

If there is a `request`, [`to_representation` calls `request.build_absolute_url()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8b7e6f2e3405d6e71488db53f2dda515d5a336c6/rest_framework/fields.py#L1558-L1559) on the URL generated, which prepends the current request's host, protocol, etc. to a partial URL.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to make that not happen, so if you always just want the image URL as a possibly relative path, derive from `drf.fields.ImageField`, e.g.

```
class URLImageField(fields.ImageField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if value:
            try:
                return value.url
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        return None
```

and
plug that in to your serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(...):
    image = URLImageField()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. I understood your point and am trying this one out next morning and will send a feedback if it worked out!

Comment: I could not stand it undone. Your explaination made me to rethink my logic so I rather removed additional logic and instead passed the request object to the serializer with DRF get_serializer() and it rocks. Thank you again!